# Odoo insert min date to datetime picker from python method

Tags: odoo

I need to insert a mindate parameter which comes from a python method, it should look something like this.

$('.cart_expected_date').datetimepicker({
format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
minDate: this.python_method(product_id)
});

it should pass the product id from the front end to the python back end and get a date from a new table, i dont know how to do 2 things.

1. I dont know how to get de product id from the e-commerce cart.
2. I dont know how to call a python method from js.

thanks

I'm expecting a way to find the product data from the e-commerce cart and pass it as a parameter to a python method.